# RX java retryWhen with timer not resubscribing to observable

Tags: java, android, networking, timer, rx-java

### Description

so I have an observable let's say `getDataObservable` it fails and emit an error sometimes and its OK, but sometimes I need it to retry again the couple of times.
then I use `retryWhen(...)` operator like `getDataObservable.retryWhen(...)`.
in this operator, I must give it a function that takes as parameter `Observable<Throwable>` (that contains the emitted error) and returns `Observable<?>` that is any kind of observable.

### I think

from my understanding about what I read in the Docs that this operator `.retryWhen(...)` uses the returned observable from the given function to subscribe to it and if it emits anything that means I am told it to resubscribe
to `getDataObservable` to retry again **but** if that returned observable emits an error that should mean **no do not retry**

### the problem

so far so good but when I return from that function a `Observable.timer(...)` (that is an observable that just emit a `long` value after some delay) I thought that `.retryWhen(...)` should subscribe to it and **WAIT** until it emits a value that tells it yes resubscribe to your parent

but instead, it finishes directly without waiting 
maybe its a threading problem or that my understanding of how that operator work is wrong and I need to work this out with `Observalbe.timer(...)` anyone that encountered that kind of problem before is glad to hear an answer

**NOTE**:the below class its a wrap over the function that it passed to `.retryWhen(...)` and instead of `.retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>() {...})`
I use `.rertyWhen(new RetryWhenObservable(5,1000))` just to wrap my retry logic in.

```
public class RetryWhenObservable implements Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {
    
    private static final String TAG = "RetryWhenObservable";
    int maxRetry, interval,retryCount = 0;

public RetryWhenObservable(int maxRetry, int interval) {
    this.maxRetry = maxRetry;
    this.interval = interval;
}
 @Override
public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
      return attempts.flatMap(throwable -> {
        if (++retryCount < this.maxRetry) {
            return Observable.timer(interval,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }else
            return Observable.error(throwable);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your source simply completes without an error so retryWhen has nothing to do. Does the lambda in the `attempts.flatMap` get called? Also `maxRetry` could be shared across all subscribers that subscribe to the `Observable` the `retryWhen` returns that could cause no retries. Plus, please check you don't simply ignore the return value of `retryWhen` and subscribing to the original source.

Comment: i tested this with an observable that only emit onError so i could test the logic
the flat map and the return function only get called once and then nothing happend no onComplete no error no resubscribe to original Observable nothing

Comment: Where is this running? In unit tests, you have to wait in a blocking manner till the source terminates, otherwise the unit test's thread moves on. Also you tell the timer to wait 1000 seconds.

Comment: This works for me as expected: https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/6069fd876a476b32fd0978ae0f0ebb11

Comment: thank you i'll check it out but i tried it in unit test and on android device in unit test i considered the threading problem i always in that situation tells the thread to sleep in order to observable to finish

Comment: lastly i discovered that my original  Single (am using Singles by the way) is calling retryWhen once and it throws an "Obserable emitted no items" error after it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems i was using this class wrong like this `.retryWhen(new RetryWhenObservable(5,1000))` and willing it will try `5` times at `1 second` intervals and didn't notice that the unit used in that class was `TimeUnit.SECONDS` so it runs the observable once and wait and wait Silly mistake :P
I modified class to overcome this in future then constructor looks like `new RetryWhenObservable(5,1000,TimeUnit.MILLIS)` to specify the time unit used
**PS :** double check the silly parts of your code first when you are debugging.